# Почему не работает if при создании динамической структуры данных (LIFO)?

Tags: c++, динамические-структуры

у меня возникли проблемы при выполнении задания: Составить программу обработки динамической структуры данных: удалить из стека L все элементы с весом, превышающим заданное значение.

Проблема заключается в том, при создании стека пропускается первый if.

Как это исправить?
По возможности пожалуйста детально объясните почему так происходит.

```cpp
struct Stack {
    int value;
    Stack *next_element = nullptr;
};

void Push(Stack* &ptr,int value) {
    if (ptr==nullptr) // при создании первого элемента пропускается (ошибка)
    {
        ptr = new Stack;
        ptr->value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        Stack* newStack = ptr;
        while (newStack->next_element != nullptr) newStack->next_element->value = value; //ошибка, ссылка в никуда
        newStack->next_element = new Stack();
        newStack->next_element->value = value;

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack *first;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Push(first, i);
    //code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит не работает первый `if`, вы в курсе что сравнивая объекты `==` вы сравниваете ссылки на объект? А они реально разные. Подумайте как иначе проверить существует ли объект.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev: "Сравнивает ссылки"? Это как? В С++ нет способа "сравнивания ссылок" в принципе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию `Push` ссылку на указатель `first`. Но ваш указатель `first` ничем не инициализирован, т.е. содержит "мусор". Вы же почему-то ожидаете, что этот "мусор" будет равен `nullptr`. Не будет.

Также непонятно, в чем заключается назначение загадочного цикла

```
while (newStack->next_element != nullptr) newStack->next_element->value = value;
```

Вы зачем-то забиваете уже существующие узлы вашей структуры одним и тем же (новым) значением. Зачем?

Comment: А еще не понятно в чем необходимость передавать в функцию ссыльку на указатель